# 504 Gateway Time-out with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, digital-ocean

I'm getting a 504 Time-out error only when my website uses Devise gem, this happens when I'm trying to access **/login** page.

I already increased timeout in unicorn and nginx but it doesn't seems to help.

Does anyone have had this problem before? And how did you fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you've posted logs.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution for my case, I was increasing the timeout in both(nginx-unicorn) with the same value so I just added more time in unicorn than nginx.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to press ctrl + R or F5.
2. Restart all of your network devices. Temporary problems with your modem, router, switches, or other networking hardware could be causing the 504 Gateway Timeout issue you're seeing. Just restarting these devices could help.
3. Check from another device to see if this problem is caused from the web server or your internet connection.